# Angular 2 change mouse icon over image or div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to Angular2 and front end development in general, 
I am trying fo make dome divisions clickable but the problem is that the mouse is not changing the shape to the hand when it comes over the div content 
I want the app to print something when I click on "PRODUCTS" and it is doing it but the mouse shape is not changing over "PRODUCTS"

example.component.html

```
 <div (click)="navigateToProducts()" > PRODUCTS</div>
```

example.component.ts

```
public navigateToProducts(){
  console.log("navigateToProducts");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a class to your div like that :

```
<div (click)="navigateToProducts()" class="myClass"> PRODUCTS</div>
```

(or ng-class, I don't know I don't use angular)

and then in your css file :

```
.myClass {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

You can write in-line css to change mouse shape

```
<div style="cursor:pointer" (click)="navigateToProducts()" > PRODUCTS</div>
```